# Subversion - Can't seem to establish a new repository

Tags: svn, repository, nearlyfreespeech

Recently I decided to establish a new repository on a fresh account with nearlyfreespeech.net. I know there is support for svn, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected.

For example, if I do this:

```
svnadmin create /home/private/svn/myproject
```

then:

```
cd /home/private/svn
mkdir mytree && mkdir mytree/tags && mkdir/trunk && mkdir/branches
```

And finally, attempt to import this:

```
svn import /home/private/svn/mytree file:///home/private/svn/myproject -m "Initial import"
```

It claims to be adding the files, but they actually don't exist anywhere. /svn/myproject remains empty, no .svn folders are produced at either the source or the destination, etc. No working copy is created.

All I really want is to establish a repository to work on a symfony based application.

Am I missing something? I'm going nuts! Thanks for any help.

Comment: I also think you have some mistakes up there with the instructions to create your directories (I'm assuming that it's a mistake when posting the question, and the actual directory structure is correct on your machine).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the part where you checkout the files. You've imported that directory structure just fine into your svn repository, but you haven't actually performed a checkout. So now you just need to remove the 'mytree' directory (and subfolders - it might be better to not remove them immediately, and instead perform the checkout to a differently named directory just to be safe), then you should be able to do:

```
svn checkout file:///home/private/svn/myproject mytree
```

This will result in a check out of your repository and it's all set and ready to go!

Comment: It's always something so simple! Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome, I still tend to get caught with simple things more often than not myself!